# i can't create android keystore in visual studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

hi I am tired to try creating android keystore in xamarin visual studio 2017 
when I click ad hoc and press plus sign to add keystore nothing saved.

I follow tut. in below page but I it doesn't add keystor.

[here the xamarin tut I follow it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows)

best regard

Answer (score 1):

You can create keystore in Android Studio if VS can't do it for some reason. The process should look similar to this in VS and then you can use it to sign your app in VS.

Comment: You will create *.jks file (key store) in Android studio. Then when you will be signing you apk in VS instead of creating new key store you should choose the one created in AS. Hope it will work for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Generate new key using command prompt:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

2) From app signing, select the import option and import the created keystore path

Comment: not work when I import keystore and click ok nothing shown in signing identity window

Comment: what do you mean by from app signing? can you give more details?